# Globally defining jQuery plugin parameters

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm making a small plugin for a theme, how do I declare the parameters (options) in one string rather than having to include them each time I call the function? The plugin has to be an external file and I need to be able to change the options locally which is why I need this sort of setup. I know this is wrong but it's the sort of thing I'm looking for -

```
var options = {minwidth: 250, maxwidth: 500, crazy: 0.6, bigger: 100};

(function($) {
$.fn.rosalind = function(options) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var elm = $(this);
    var width = Math.floor(Math.random()*options.minwidth) + options.maxwidth - options.minwidth;
    var poswidth = $('#shell').width() - width;
    var left = Math.floor(Math.random()*poswidth);
    elm.css({'margin-left': left, 'margin-top': top, 'width': width}).attr('width', width);
    var height = $(this).height();
    var ratio = Math.floor(options.bigger*height/width);
    var wratio = width/options.maxwidth;
    elm.attr({'rel': ratio, 'alt': wratio});
    top += Math.floor(Math.random()*ratio*options.crazy + wratio*ratio/2);
  });
 };
})(jQuery);

$('.post:visible').rosalind();
```

thank you

Comment: Found the answer! Similar to my example but it needs to be `$('.post:visible').rosalind(options);` :D

Answer (score 0):

Usually in the plugins i've seen they use something like this:

```
$.fn.rosalind = function(options) {
     var settings= {minwidth: 250, maxwidth: 500, crazy: 0.6, bigger: 100};
     //extend defaults if options are provided
     if(options && typeof options === "object"){
          $.extend(settings, options);
     }
```

Comment: I had something like this before but really need to define the variables outside of the function

Answer (score 0):

One option is to start with a boilerplate like the following that takes care of extending a set of defaults with the parameters that the function was called with:

```
// start of anonymous function, no global namespace is used. Formal parameter $ is passed the jQuery object, see closing of function definition.
(function ($) {
    // define default parameters for myPlugin. These can be overridden by the call, or from data attached to the jQuery object
    var defaults = {optionOne: true, optionTwo: 'CALI', callback: function () {/* code here, or leave it out of the defaults so it will be null by default */}};
    // this next line adds myPlugin to the jQuery functions because ".fn" is an alias for "prototype". The function call enables behavior like $("selector").myPlugin('action', {optionOne: false});
    $.fn.myPlugin = function (action, options) {
        var passed = options, // passed will store the options that were passed in. This allows us to see what was sent after the options are expanded with defaults.
            obj, // the jQuery object being worked with -- check to see if this can be handled with "el" locally.
            dataStore, // object to store persistant data for the jQuery objects being worked with.
            result; // used if we are passed a call that requires returning a result rather than returning the jQuery collection we were passed.

        // code here, functions to be called as actions
        function initialize() {} function single() {} function getDual() {} function setDual() {}

        function getOptions(el) {
            var optionsPrior = el.data('myPlugin:options'), // attempt to load prior settings
                dataStorePrior = el.data('myPlugin:data'); // load any stored data

            options = (optionsPrior !== undefined) ? optionsPrior : $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options); // sets options either to prior options or extends the default options with those that were passed in.
            options = $.metadata ? $.extend(true, {}, options, el.metadata()) : options; // check for settings attached to the current object

            if (dataStorePrior !== undefined) { // if there is a prior data store populate the active datastore with it.
                dataStore = dataStorePrior;
            }
        }

        function setOptions(el) {
            el.data('myPlugin:options', options); // store setting to the object
            el.data('myPlugin:data', dataStore); // store datastore to the object
        }

        // check to see if the first parameter passed is an object instead of an string containing an action, if so then use the object as options and set the action to initalize.
        if (!action || typeof (action) === 'object') {
            options = action;
            action = 'initialize';
        }

        // process each element in the jQuery object collection
        this.each(function (el) {

            // store reference to the currently processing jQuery object -- check to see the value of this over using "el" from the function
            var obj = $(this);

            getOptions(obj); // load the current options

            if (action && typeof (action) === 'string') { // this is an alternative to the use of "var methods = {function methodOne ()..." that allows a single action to have both a set and get that can call different functions.
                switch (action) {
                case 'initialize':
                    initialize(obj);
                    break;
                case 'singleOptionAction':
                    single(obj);
                    break;
                case 'dualModeAction':
                    //return and set
                    if (passed === undefined) {
                        result = getDual;
                    } else {
                        setDual(obj, passed);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break; // we have no listed method that matched what they sent
                }
            }
            setOptions(el);
            // code here
        });

        return this; // this enables chaining; without it the jQuery collection that is passed in is not passed further along the chain. Alternatively if you are trying to filter or modify the jQuery collection you'll want to return a modified version of this.
    };
}(jQuery)); // end anonymous function definition and execute it, passing in the jQuery object.  
                // jQuery should already be loaded, and the "$" reference is used only within your function definition, keeping this reference safe from being clobbered by other scripts.
                // After execution, your plugin is defined and ready to use.
```

There are many ways to write a jQuery plugin and this example just shows one set of choices.

Comment: thanks but I have to be able to define the variables completely outside the function